# Check if array contains element when the array can be nil

Tags: arrays, swift

I declare an empty array

```
var myArray: [DWTeaser]?
```

than I want to go through t elements and add them to the array, every element should be added only one time

```
for t in alltElement {
    if !self.myArray!.contains(t){
        self.myArray?.append(t)
    }
}
```

The app crashes and I think it's because that the first time myArray is nil. How can I fix that?

Comment: what is `this`?  Do you mean `self`?

Comment: Why have an optional array?  Couldn't you just have an empty one?  `var myArray = [DWTeaser]()`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep it as an Optional, just initialize the array before accessing it `myArray = []`

Comment: I need it as an Optional. 
@Keiwan thank you

Comment: Never force unwrap with `!`.  Use `?` or an `if let`.

Comment: `if !(self.myArray?.contains(t) ?? true) {}`. If there is no array you don't need to add it.

Comment: What result to you expect  if the array is `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
for t in alltElement {
    if !self.myArray!.contains(t){
        self.myArray?.append(t)
    }
}
```

with the following:

```
for t in alltElement {
    if (self.myArray?.contains(t)).map(!) ?? false {
        self.myArray?.append(t)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

Replace

```
var myArray: [DWTeaser]?
```

by this

```
var myArray = [DWTeaser]()
```

then do this:

```
for t in alltElement {
    if !self.myArray.contains(t){
        self.myArray.append(t)
    }
}
```